# How to change OpenCV video library on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed OpenCV on Ubuntu 14 , when i want to feed it's function with a video , it told me to install ffmpeg libraries but as i know, ffmpeg is replaced with another decoder library on Ubuntu 14, How can i fix it or use another library ?

Comment: How did you install openCV?

Comment: I have downloaded its package from sourceforge and did exactly as [this link](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) documentation said.

Comment: Since you build OpenCV yourself instead of using binaries you might have to choose to use ffmpeg during the build similar to WITH_OPENGL=ON etc.

Comment: Your link says "Check that the above command produces no error and that in particular it reports FFMPEG as YES." Did you do that?